# JSP Page Directive

Tags: jsp, page-directives

I have 2 difference page directive codes in my jsp, i don't know what is the difference between **contentType**, **charset**, and **pageEncoding**, i read thru [Oracle JSP Globalization Support](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14099_19/web.1012/b14014/jspnls.htm) but didn't understand quite well , can anyone explain the difference in simpler way?

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=GBK"%>
```

VERSUS

```
<%@page contentType="text/html;charset=GBK" pageEncoding="GBK"%>
```

Comment: All the directives do is add tags to the <head> section and/or the http response headers. I'd just try the different variations and see what you get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.satollo.net/jsp-and-the-content-type-charset-and-the-page-encoding-attribute

## ContentType charset

The contentType charset is how the servlet container which runs the JSP  must send to the browser the text generated by the page.

## PageEncoding

The pageEncoding directive is used to correctly read the JSP from the file system. Since even the JSP is a text but a file is a sequence of bytes on disk, it can be correctly read only knowing the charset to use.

Then:

ContentType charset: How the client have to interpret the file

PageEncoding: How to read the jsp from the filesystem